# itextsharp.NumberOfPages returns a wrong value

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm working on a C# application and i'm using itextsharp(v5.5.2) to read pdf documents. 
 
I have a problem to read some pdf files because the "PdfReader.NumberOfPages" attibute sometimes returns a wrong value. 
i.e.: a document contains 18 pages(adobe reader) but the attribute "PdfReader.NumberOfPages" return 2. 
 
When i try with this code(for testing) to get the text from a page by the page number

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fileInfo.FullName);
PdfReaderContentParser pdfReaderContentParser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
ITextExtractionStrategy iTextExtractionStrategy = pdfReaderContentParser.ProcessContent(myPageNumber, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
String pdfText = iTextExtractionStrategy.GetResultantText();
```

, I have the results:

```
if myPageNumber = 1  => return the text from the page 1 
if myPageNumber = 2  => return the text from the page 8!!! 
if myPageNumber = 3  => create an error as expected (the reader "see" only 2 pages)
```

I discovered a possible cause of this problem but i'm not sure of it: the type of the font type.  
 
When I have "type1" in the document, i don't have problems. But i have the problem with the truetype font type.
I unfortunatly can't share the problematic pdf files.

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: I've seen this behavior only for PDF documents based on the XML Forms Architecture (in which case, it's perfectly normal). I haven't seen this ever with traditional PDF documents. So the real question is: what kind of PDF document are you talking about? Show us the PDF!

Comment: Exactly, please share sample documents illustrating the issue.

Comment: Thank for the information. I unfortunatly havn't the permission to share the file(accounting information). I'm going to try to reproduce the issue with a new pdf file.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie You're right. I didn't even know the different type of pdf file(thank for the explanations: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h0wzj84tnmw).

Comment: This is the way to programmatically detect XML Forms Architecture in C# (with itextsharp) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742161/how-to-programmatically-detect-xfa-adobe-xml-forms-architecture-dynamic-pdf). Now, I'm searching for a free converter (if someone know one...). Thank for the help.

Comment: There is no free solution to convert XFA into ordinary PDF. Either you buy a LiveCycle ES license from Adobe (very expensive) or you buy a license for XFA Worker from us (not expensive: the same price of an iText license. For instance: if you paid $2200 for your iTextSharp license, you pay an extra $2200 for the XFA Worker add-on). XFA is a very extensive spec. I don't think any developer can afford implementing this spec without being paid for it.

Comment: Thank a lot for all these informations. Topic closed. All the best.